# How to get values of the rows of a table that are filled in the jsp in the Action class in Struts 2?

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts, struts-1, struts2-jquery

I have the following jsp in which I have an option of adding and deleting rows of the table and in each row of the table which have the same fields I have to fill in  the options and submit the form.

In the action class how do I retrieve the values of the row which I have filled in the JSP as there are more than one row that I fill in the table ?

This is my JSP:

```
<table id="fragmentTable" style="height: 100%; width: 100%">

    <tr class="tableRow" style='height: 5%;'>
      <td class='' style='position: absolute; left: 75%;'>
    <button value="Add Row" type="button" onclick="return addRow1();">Add Row</button>
    <button value="Delete Row" type="button" onclick="return deleteRow          ('dataTable')">Delete Row</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><br><br>
    <table id="dataTable" border="1" width=100% height=30% class='blueBorder'>
    <thead>
    <tr class='rowHeader'>
          <th width='14%'>Select</th>
          <th width='14%'>Opening Brace</th>
          <th width='14%'>Parameter</th>
          <th width='14%'>Relational Operator</th>
          <th width='14%'>Value</th>
          <th width='15%'>Closing Brace</th>
          <th width='15%'>Logical Operator</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>


        <tr class='rowData' id=1>
<td>
<s:checkbox theme="simple" id="sel" name="GRF_FRAGID" value="false" /></td>
<td ><s:select headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select" list="#{'1':'(', '2':'((','3':'(((','4':'((((','5':'((((('}" name="GRF_OPNGBRCES" /></td>
<td>
<s:select label="Mode" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select" list="#{'1':'=', '2':'!='}"
    name="GRF_OP" />
</td>
<td>
<s:textfield name="Country"/>
</td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: you have 2 options either keep trek which row has been changed or submit entire data to your action class.

Answer (score 3):

I don't understand exactly your page, but you need to use iterator (as suggested by @NidhishKrishnan ) and to point to the index through its IteratorStatus object:

```
<s:iterator value="yourlist" status="ctr" >
  <tr>
    <td><s:textfield name="yourlist[%{#ctr.index}].country"/></td>
  </tr>
 </s:iterator>
```

`country` should be written with first letter lowercase.

If you need to generate new rows with javascript, you must generate the same HTML that is "outputted" by the `<s:textfield/>` tag (click on `View Source` of your browser, and understand how it is generated).

This will create on the target Action (that must have the same `List` with a `setter`) a new List containing all the values from the page.

No need to act on one row singularly, you can update (for example) 10 rows in one post with this.

---

**EDIT**

Answering your comment, if you do not have any initial value, no iteration is involved: you can define the first row as the first element of the list, using the same syntax that you would use to add a new row.

There is no need to *start* from a List, the only requirement is to post list-formatted HTML elements to be set in the *destination* List.

Use **[this article](http://www.programmingforfuture.com/2011/02/how-to-handle-values-from-dynamically.html)** as an example, to understand which javascript and HTML you need to create.

Comment: How do I enter the iterator as initially the list is empty?

Comment: I have seen this link but I need to generate dropdowns, dont know how to do it using their javascript

Comment: As a hint, start with something really basic but that is working (one input field, add row, edit row, remove row, etc), only then add complexity. For the select, you can generate a select in javascript by using HTML `<select>` tag and an `<s:iterator>` around the `<option>` element. You can do this at page loading, and saving in javascript the "template" of your select(s), that you will attach to every new row by referencing its javascript var.